# Parse all matches in a string in tcl

Tags: string, tcl

I have a string as follows

```
set temp "
temp   : value
temp1  : value1
tempvalue
abc    = 23:445:726
abcdef = 456::985
abcdef = 123:45:7
abcdef = 098:45:56:8
"
```

In this I want an output in which the values after "=" should be set to one variable. Output should be

```
"456::985 123:45:7 098:45:56:8".
```

I used

```
set result [regexp "abcdef\\s*=\\s*(\\S*)" $temp match v1]
```

but not able to get all

I have got the answer using regexp with -inline -all and -line, to store the result in list and then traverse through it to get the values. I need a one liner

```
set result [regexp -inline -all -line "abcdef\\s*=\\s*(\\S*)" $temp]
```

Output is

```
{abcdef = 456::985} 456::985 {abcdef = 123:45:7} 123:45:7 {abcdef = 098:45:56:8} 098:45:56:8
```

Then traverse through this to set them all in one string. But i want to know if there is any  easy way to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Given this example you don't need regexp. Split the lines into pieces and create a new list.

```
set r {}
foreach line [split $temp \n] {
    if {[string trim $line] eq ""} continue;             # skip blank lines
    lappend r [string trim [lindex [split $line =] end]]
}
puts $r
```

That will give one list with just the bits after the equals sign. If you treat it as a string, then it works as a string with each element of the list separated by a space.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using line-oriented matching, take advantage of the line anchor:

```
% regexp -inline -all -line {\S+$} $temp
456::985 123:45:7 098:45:56:8
```

So, to save the values as a *string*:

```
set values [join [regexp -inline -all -line {\S+$} $temp]]
```

If there may not be whitespace after the equal, use the pattern `{[^=\s]+$}`

My whole answer assumes there's only going to be one equal sign per line.

---

Responding to the updated sample input:

```
foreach {m word} [regexp -inline -all -line {=\s*(\S+)$} $temp] {
    lappend words $word
}
puts [join $words]
```

```
23:445:726 456::985 123:45:7 098:45:56:8
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in my case i will have some cases separated  by ":" which is also coming in the result. Can you please suggest me a way without using "-line" option. By using back reference of regexp as in python

Comment: If you're changing your requirements, you have to update your question to give a better example.

Comment: I have modified it can you please check now

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach: think of each line as 3 tokens: key, equal sign, and value:

```
set result {}
foreach {key eq_sign value} $temp { lappend result $value }
```

This approach is simple to understand, but it will not work if the value contains spaces.